# Wordpress custom css in menu to show image when there will be sub-menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In wordpress I am just developing a theme. Here in menu I want my menu should be exactly like http://www.usps.com. I have done all the css for menu. But I am struck at a point. In the reference menu you can see there is one arrow mark with all the menu item. But in my case I want little bit different. I want when there will be a sub-menu then only the arrow will show otherwise there will be no arrow mark. Can some one tell me how to do that? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I have done many Wordpress different templates, and I encounter this many times, I did it with javascript (jQuery). I find the `<li>` with `<ul>` and I add sometimes a class parent or other, defense to you.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you have to target element using css is mean where you need to show arrow image 
you have to write in css or also you can use this dd smooth menu in this below link it is free and downloadable and very easy in use 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm